# Scripts tags are getting executed even after encoding in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-encode

I am using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(input) to encode the html script tags to prevent XSS..
the encoding is working but when the content gets dislpalyed on the browser the scripts are running..

here's my code,

```
<address>" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dr["Street"]) + ", " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dr["City"])       + ", " + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(dr["State"]) + ", " + dr["ZipCode"] + "</address>"
```

in the dr["Street"] I am passing "alert('fdsf')"

Comment: instead of HttpUtility.HtmlEncode use Server.HtmlEncode()...

Comment: its still not working ....I also have an anchor tag and I have and I have passed same script tag and its working fine with that..but not with this address tag

Comment: Please show the resulting HTML as it appears in the page source.